# Devise: Logging out a user from all domains

Tags: devise

I've got a Rails app that uses two different domains (not sub-domains). A user can be authenticated on both domains, and, currently, logging in or out in the two domains for the same user is completely independent.

What I'm looking for is a way to force the user out from all sessions he has open, on any domain and any browser the user could have logged in to. For now the only way I found to do this is to change the password - it looks like all other data resides in the session cookie, ie, only on the client side.

I know I could store the forced logout information myself and then use the sign_out(current_user) helper method with a controller filter, but I was wandering if there was a default way to do it with devise.